# RFC 1006 ACTIVE/PASSIVE

Tags: tcp

What is the difference between ACTIVE and PASSIVE connect in RFC 1006 TCP connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's explained here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793

> A passive OPEN request means that the process wants to accept incoming connection requests rather than attempting to initiate a connection.

In short passive OPEN are `listen()` and active OPEN are `connect()`.